# Is there a way to filter and see all the videos I shared on my Facebook profile?

Tags: facebook, search, video, sharing

I want to see only the videos I shared on my profile by filtering it. I thought it can be done in activity log, since you can search your posts, but a lot of videos I shared in groups and pages show up all together, so outcome is a mass.

Going through all of it and just picking up which videos you shared in your profile takes so much time. I hope there is a easier way to filter these that you guys know of.

PS: There was a way, but that project is dead now: http://archivedbook.com